# Detect update in observable prop

Tags: reactjs, observable, mobx, mobx-react

I have a component that has an observable as property:

```
class Store {
   @observable color = "red" 
}

const store = new Store(); 

@observer
class MyComponent extends React.Component {  
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // Not called!
    console.log("Component will receive props", nextProps.store.color)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Component did mount", this.props.store.color)  
  }
  changeColor = () => {
    this.props.store.color = (this.props.store.color==="red")? "blue":"red";
  };
  render() {
    return <div>
        color: {this.props.store.color}  
        <button onClick={this.changeColor}>Change color</button>   
    </div>
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent store={store} />, document.body)
```

My problem is that `componentWillReceiveProps` is never called when the observed variable is changed (by clicking on the button), nor is `componentDidReceiveProps` or `shouldComponentUpdate`. However I can see in the rendered code that the color is indeed changed in the store.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: use `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate`

---

The object `Store` passed as a prop never changes, even when its content changes. The trick of using `@observable` is that it will trigger the update in the component without changing the props. So using lifecycle functions such as `shouldComponentUpdate`, `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentDidReceiveProps` won't work with since they are triggered when either the component's props or state changes. The mobx doc explains it well in the [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#about-shouldcomponentupdate) section.

So, to catch an update in an observable, we must go a bit deeper in the lifecycle stack and use `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate`.

So, the code should look like this:

```
@observer
class MyComponent extends React.Component {  
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // Not called! 
    console.log("Component will receive props", nextProps.store.color)
  }
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.log("Component will update", nextProps.store.color)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Component did mount", this.props.store.color)  
  }
  changeColor = () => {
    this.props.store.color = (this.props.store.color==="red")? "blue":"red";
  };
  render() {
    return <div>
        color: {this.props.store.color}  
        <button onClick={this.changeColor}>Change color</button>   
    </div>
  }
};
```

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/voqugezaya/edit?js,console,output

Under the cover, `mobx-react` uses the `forceUpdate` function to trigger the component to re-render without necessarily changing the objects in its props (only their content changes).

Also, there is a new function introduced by mobx, which is quite helpful for debugging: [`componentWillReact`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#componentwillreact-lifecycle-hook).

Comment: the weird part here is I completed an app where `componentWillReceiveProps` is actually called. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should the mobx lifecycle hook functions be used instead? (e.g: componentWillReact). See the documentation at https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observer-component.html

Comment: `componentWillReact` is indeed valid to. I prefer not using it because it will be triggered only by mobx events (so not when props are updated). Also, there is no `componentDidReact` so it doesn't cover the lifecycle as well.